# How did Tulukka Nachiyar become Ranganatha's consort at Srirangam temple?

Tags: vishnu, temple

https://navrangindia.blogspot.in/2015/11/sri-ranganathar-and-his-muslim-consort.html

> Lord Ranganatha Swamy appeared in the chief priest' dreams  and
>   pronounced that he had now taken Surathani (derived from Sultani) to
>   be his wife and she too had to be given all the temple honors and
>   worship  that were given to the other Nachiyars (Nachiyar is a term
>   used in Tamil Vaishnava   theology for the divine consort of the
>   presiding deity)/consorts. The Bhattar then conveyed this dream to the
>   temple authorities and, accordingly, a shrine was built for the Muslim
>   consort of Lord Ranganatha.
>
> The Muslim princess not only had  gained divinity through her deep
>   devotion but also the status of Lord's consort. Idol  worship in Islam
>   is a taboo, so, she was worshipped in the form of a painting, richly
>   decorated with gems and gold and still regular pujas and other rituals
>   are held to day. The daily naivaidhyam (divine food) will include
>   chappathis, butter, etc, traditional North Indian food.

It looks like she is maintaining her Muslim identity, since an idol has not been made for her.

And apparently Lakshmi took this seriously

> Terribly upset over Lord accepting the Muslim woman as his consort,
>   Ranganayaki Thayyar (goddess), Lords consort moved away from him in
>   anger and rage. Hence, there is  a  separate  shrine  for Thayyar. In
>   the recent Samprokshanam held at Srirangam temple on the 18th of
>   November, 2015, a separate Yagasala and Agni Kundams were arranged on
>   the premises of Thayyar Sannidhi (shrine) as she is ''Padi Thaanda
>   Pathini.'' Tradition has it that Goddess Ranganayaki has never come
>   out of the shrine after Lord's acceptance of Surathani. Lord made
>   several vein attempts to make a compromise with Thayyar but it never
>   worked out.

Is this all at the folklore level or is there any scriptural support?